# Passing an instantiated class to concrete class derived by Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, repository-pattern

I have a system that I'm using to test some new architecture. I have the following setup (In MVC2 .Net - C Sharp):

View < Controller < Service < Repository < DB

I'm using Castle Windsor as my DI (IoC) controller, and this is working just fine in both the Service and Repo layers. However, I'm now at a point where I would like to pass an Entity Framework (DatabaseNameEntity) to the constructor to the Service, and then to the Repo, so that I have something similar to a Unit of Work pattern per request (This feels like what I'm trying to achieve anyway) - and I'm having trouble working out how this can be done using Castle Windsor.

Am I going off on a silly tangent? Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How would you like to pass that? From the call site?
Use Typed Factory Facility for that.